# Checking for internet connectivity in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have created a form in android which includes fields like firstname,lastname,mobile no etc.
I am using a webservice to send this data to server and its happening perfectly.Now I want to check for internet connectivity and if user is not connected to internet when he is filling form and user submits the form, the form should get uploaded to server whenever user get back in internet connectivtiy.
Can anyone tell me way for achieving this functionality.
I tried using broadcast receiver to check for internet connectivity but not able to get form uploaded. Also do I have to save form fields in permanent storage.Currently I am saving them in bean class.

I am pasting my complete form activity class code.
Let me know if any changes are required

```
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Boolean isValidEmail = false;
            String first_name = firstname.getText().toString().trim();
            String last_name = lastname.getText().toString().trim();
            String country = nation.getText().toString().trim();
            String mail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String firm = company.getText().toString().trim();
            String mobile = phone.getText().toString().trim();
            String post = title.getText().toString().trim();
            String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
            if (first_name.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your first name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                registrationBean.setFname(first_name);
                if (last_name.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your last name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    registrationBean.setLname(last_name);
                    if (firm.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your company name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        registrationBean.setCompany(firm);
                        if (post.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your designation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            registrationBean.setTitle(post);
                            if (mobile.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                registrationBean.setPhone(mobile);

                                if (mail.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !mail.matches(emailPattern)) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                } else {
                                    registrationBean.setMail(mail);

                                    if (country.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your country of residence", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        registrationBean.setNation(country);
                                        if (checked==true && registrationBean!=null)
                                        {

                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please accept terms and conditions",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    });
    if (img_path.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        retake_photo.setAlpha((float) 0.6);
    }
}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] options = {"Take a Picture", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityForm.this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Select Profile Photo!");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take a Picture")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                img_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/temp.jpg";
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    photoPickerIntent.addCategory(photoPickerIntent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 2);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    img_path = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString();
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            try {
                bitmap = AppUtils.decodeFile(file.getPath(), 100, 100);
                registrationBean.setImage(file.getPath());
                //  ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(file.getPath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (bitmap != null) {

                iv_profile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                retake_photo.setAlpha(1);
            }


            break;
        case 2:
            try {
                String uriImage;
              imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                imageStream.close();
                if (selectedImage != null) {
                    iv_profile.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                    retake_photo.setAlpha(1);

                }


                 uriImage=imageUri.toString();
                registrationBean.setImage(uriImage);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }
}
private void callRegistrationService()
{
    String fname=registrationBean.getFname();
    String lname=registrationBean.getLname();
    String company=registrationBean.getCompany();
    String mobile=registrationBean.getPhone();
    String designation=registrationBean.getTitle();
    String image=getPath(imageUri);
    String email=registrationBean.getMail();
    String country=registrationBean.getNation();
    //email,firstName,lastName,userImage,company,title,phone,country
    new RegistrationAsyncTask(this, email, fname, lname, image, company, designation, mobile, country).execute();
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
            // Do something
            callRegistrationService();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Such a nasty `if...else..if...else` construction. You need to implement sort of validator which will make this in a proper way. Or, at least, you change it to `if (!check) { Toast.makeText(); return; }` sequence.

Comment: that is a validator for form fields

Answer (score 0):

"Now I want to check for internet connectivity and if user is not connected to internet"

This might help you.

```
 public void isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if(!(netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable())){
                isInternetAvailable=true;
            }
            else
                isInternetAvailable=false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

create class Global.java

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import com.affinity.affinityrescue.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class Global
{
    public static String _useremail;
    public static String _user_id;
    public static final String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
    public static String regId = "";
    static Context context;
    static DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

    public static boolean isNetworkconn(Context ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;

        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

        }

        return false;
    }

    // THIS METHOD IS USED FOR SHOW DIALOG WHEN NO INTERNET
    public static void showDialogOnNoInternet(final Activity activity)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alt_bld.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alt_bld.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
        alt_bld.setMessage("Please check your internet connection");
        alt_bld.setCancelable(false);
        alt_bld.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alt_bld.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alt_bld.show();
    }
}
```

write code where you need.

```
if (Global.isNetworkconn(getActivity())) {
//code for success.
}
else
{
   Global.showDialogOnNoInternet(getActivity());
}
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I want even on app close app should check for internet connectivity and when internet is available it shouls upload form to server using web service.

What I think this behaviour cannot be acheived.